# flutter_form_builder set value of field programmatically not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-form-builder

I'm trying to set the value of a field programmatically using [flutter_form_builder](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder) and it doesn't seem to be in the docs.

the controller:

```
class LoggedOutNicknameController extends GetxController {
  AnimationController animateController;
  bool formValid;

  final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();

  @override
  void onInit() {}

  @override
  void onReady() {
    final box = GetStorage();
    box.erase();
    if (box.read<dynamic>('nickname') != null &&
        box.read<dynamic>('nickname') != '') {
      print(box.read<dynamic>('nickname')); // prints the value eg 'James'
      final fff = box.read<String>('nickname');
      formKey.currentState.setAttributeValue('nickname', fff);
    }
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {}

  void onFormChange() {
    formValid = formKey.currentState.validate();
  }
}
```

After that code there supposedly sets the value, the value does not display in my text input.

The view:

```
Expanded(
              flex: 4,
              child: FormBuilder(
                  key: controller.formKey,
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                  child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        VpSubtitle1(
                            context,
                            'So nice to meet you! What do your friends call you?',
                            TextAlign.center),
                        FormBuilderTextField(
                          attribute: 'nickname',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          decoration:
                              const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Nickname...'),
                          validators: [FormBuilderValidators.required()],
                        )
                      ]))),
```

Why does the value not show up in the text input?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is very simple and clarified in the official docs,

You can either change the value of one field at a time like so:

```
_formKey.currentState.fields['color_picker'].didChange(Colors.black);
```

Or multiple fields value like so:

```
_formKey.currentState.patchValue({
  'age': '50',
  'slider': 6.7,
  'filter_chip': ['Test 1'],
  'choice_chip': 'Test 2',
  'rate': 4,
  'chips_test': [
    Contact('Andrew', 'stock@man.com', 'https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX4057996.jpg'),
  ],
});
```

Refer to this part in the docs:  [flutter_form_builder: Programmatically changing field value](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder#programmatically-changing-field-value)

Comment: Where should I change the _formKey.currentState.fields['color_picker'].didChange(Colors.black);
At initState, it is null

Comment: Why do you want to change a field value in the event of `initState()`? while `initState` is running, the fields are have not built yet, so you can not change their values, I thing you are trying to set an initial value for the field, if this is the case, then use `initialValue` property.

Comment: Yes, I want to show the data from database to edit the form. How come I miss the initialValue. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, it happens, you are always welcome.